# Modify on-the-fly verbose_name in a model field on django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have this sample model working with the admin

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Text in here'), max_length=100)
```

with verbose_name set as ugettext_lazy 'Text in here', but sometimes, depending on the site_id i want to present a diferent verbose name, so I modified the **init** in this way

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Author, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #some logic in here
    self._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name = _('Other text')
```

It works, displaying the 'Other text' instead the 'Text in here'... except for the very first time the author/add view is used.

¿Is it the right way to do it? ¿How can i fix the first time problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't modify elements of the model. There's all sorts of metaclass stuff going on in model definitions that will break things, as you have discovered.

Instead, define a custom form and change the field label in the `__init__` method there.

Comment: Perfect. 
When I created the custom form the verbose_name displayed in the right way. Even it works if im making the changes in the model, but as you suggested im moving all the personalization to the form to avoid breaking things.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add `verbose_name`

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name = 'Other text')
```

Comment: This is not what the original poster asked.